# Helper for edit/show/destroy Link with an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to make nice helpers so that i can use these style:

```
edit(category)
destroy(post.comment.first)
show(@user)
```

and we get the selected link with a nice image.

can anyone tell me if i am doing it right or is there a better magical rails way to get the url?

```
def show(object)
  link_to image_tag("admin/show.png"), eval("admin_{object.class.to_s.downcase}_path(#    {object.id})")
end

def edit(object)    
  link_to image_tag("admin/edit.png"), eval("edit_admin_#{object.class.to_s.downcase}_path(#{object.id})")
end

def destroy(object)    
  link_to image_tag("admin/destroy.png"), eval("admin_#{object.class.to_s.downcase}_path(#{object.id})"), :method=>:delete, :confirm=>"Do you really want to delete this?"
end
```

this is working fine but i am looking for the magic rails way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `eval` with `send`, and replace `downcase` with `underscore` which is rails' convention

```
send("admin_{object.class.to_s.underscore}_path", object.id)
```

BTW, rails can do these for you:

```
# equals to your `show(object)`
link_to image_tag('admin/show.png'), [:admin, object]
```

Comment: what is the difference ? eval is evil? :-)

Comment: `link_to image_tag('admin/show.png'), [:edit, :admin, object]`
works great. thanks

Comment: @huanson `eval` will call parser to parse the string into ruby code then run it, which is too slow at runtime. `send` just find the corresponding method and apply it.